# Find largest number of disjoint paths with lenght $k$ in a tree

Tags: algorithms, greedy-algorithms

Consider this problem from [Jeff book](https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/book/04-greedy.pdf)

> Given a rooted tree $T$ and an integer $k$ as input, and it should
> compute the largest possible number of disjoint paths in $T$ , where
> each path has length $k$. Do not assume that T is a binary tree.

How we can use greedy approach to solve above problem?

Comment: We ask that references satisfy scholarly requirements: please include at least the title of the book and the full name of the author, and the chapter and exercise number, so that others with the same question are more likely to be able to find this page by search.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add, as stated in the book, that, in a path, "all moves must move away from the ground" (meaning that a path cannot contains two children of the same node). That is an important information.

Now, you should consider a path from a leaf of maximal depth, delete it and rince and repeat.

For the correctness, consider a solution (a set of path of length $k$), and prove that there exists a solution of the same size with a path from a leaf of maximal depth.

For a detailled proof of correctness:

Let us prove by induction on the size of the tree that the algorithm is correct and optimal.

- base case: if the tree is empty, the algorithm stops as there is no path. Hence, it is optimal.
- inductive step: suppose the algorithm is correct for every tree of size $\leqslant n$, $n$ being a natural number. Let $T$ be a tree of size $n+1$ and $x$ be the leaf of maximum depth among all nodes of $T$ (if there are several such leaves, choose arbitrarily).

  Since "all moves must move away from the ground", there exists an unique path starting from $x$, let's say $p=(x = x_0, x_1, x_2, …, x_k)$, where for $i = 0, …, k-1$, $x_{i+1}$ is the parent of $x_i$.

  Let us show that there is an optimal solution containing the path $p$. Consider a solution $S =\{p_1, …, p_m\}$, where $p_j$'s are paths of length $k$, and $m$ is maximal (meaning that $S$ is an optimal solution). One of the following is true:

  - one of the $p_j$ is equal to $p$; then there is nothing to do.
  - the subtree rooted in $x_k$ does not contain a node in a path $p_j$. Then adding the path $p$ to $S$ would yield into a better solution, which means that $S$ wasn't optimal.
  - the subtree rooted in $x_k$ contains a node in a path $p_j$. Then no other path in $S$ contains a node in the subtree rooted in $x_k$, because any path containing a node in this subtree contains $x_k$ (because $x$ is supposed to be a leaf of maximum depth). That means that $(S\cup \{p\}) \setminus \{p_j\}$ is a valid solution and of same size as $S$, hence optimal.

  Now consider the tree $T$ where the subtree rooted in $x_k$ is deleted. Such a tree $T'$ is of size $\leqslant n$, therefore we can use the induction hypothesis and the algorithm will return an optimal solution for $T'$, and adding the path $p$, we get an optimal solution for $T$.

Comment: Why this algorithm is correct? Can you give me some hint about the correctness?

Comment: @ART I added a hint.

Comment: After many days, I can't use you hint to proof correctness of the algorithm, could you give more hint about correctness of the idea? Thank you.

Comment: I tried as follow: Suppose optimal solution contains additional path $\pi$ that not exists in the answer of our greedy algorithm. Also I try to show that such a path no exists at all. At this step I got stuck.

Comment: @ART I added the proof.

Comment: Thank you. In the Jeff book says:  Now suppose each vertex in T has an associated reward, and your goal is to
maximize the total reward of the vertices in your paths, instead of the total
number of paths. Show that your greedy algorithm does not always return the
optimal reward.

Comment: Can we solve that case with dynamic programming? If possible for you, could you give me some hint that how I can solve above problem with dynamic programing?

Comment: That's another question, please make another post.