# Largest number of disjoint paths of length $k$ and maximum reward in a tree

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, greedy-algorithms

Consider exercise 23(c) of chapter "Greedy Algorithms", [*Algorithms*](https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/book/04-greedy.pdf) by Jeff Erickson.

> Given a tree $T=(V,E)$ in which each node has a reward, and
> $k\in\mathbb{N}$, our goal is to find a set $S$ of paths, each having length exactly $k$, such that the paths in $S$ are pairwise vertex-disjoint and and the overall reward (defined as the sum of the rewards of all the nodes that belong to some path in $S$) is maximized. (note that a path cannot contains two children of the same node)

According to [this link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/151065/find-largest-number-of-disjoint-paths-with-lenght-k-in-a-tree/151066?noredirect=1#comment317662_151066), if the weights were unit then the problem above could be solved by a greedy approach. However, a greedy algorithm does not always return the optimal reward for the current situation.

How can we solve the problem above using dynamic programing?

Comment: I don't understand the problem statement. First, $k$ doesn't appear anywhere. Second, it's not clear what is being maximized — the number of disjoint paths, or the sum of rewards.

Comment: Thank you for your suggest. I edit the question.

Comment: This is how I interpret what's written in the question: let $r^*$ be the maximum reward that can be obtained by selecting any number of (pairwise) vertex-disjoint paths such that (i) each path has length exactly $k$ and (ii) each path goes from an ancestor to a descendant in the tree. We want to select a set $S$ of vertex-disjoint paths so that (i) and (ii) are still satisfied, the overall reward is $r^*$, and $|S|$ is maximized. Is this correct? I suspect this is not the problem you had in mind.

Comment: I have edited your question with what I think the intended problem was. Please check if it is correct.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a vertex $v$, let $r(v)$ denote $v$'s rewards, let $C_v$ be the set of $v$'s children, and let $T_v$ denote the subtree of $T$ rooted in $v$.
Given a vertex $x$ at depth $d_T(x) \ge k$ in $T$, we denote by $x_i$ the $i$-th ancestor of $x$ in $T$ (in particular $x_0=x$).
Define $C_T(x) =\left( \bigcup_{i=0,\dots,d_T(x)} C(x_i) \right) \setminus \{ x_0, \dots, x_{d_T(x)} \}$.

Define $OPT[v]$ as the maximum revenue that can be obtained when the instance consists of $T_v$.
Let $r$ be the root of $T$. We observe the following: if there is an optimal set of paths $S$ that is not empty, and $x$ is the lower endpoint of a path in $S$ that has minimum depth in $T$, then:
$$
OPT[r] = \sum_{i=0}^k r(x_i) + \sum_{u \in C_T(x)}  OPT[u].
$$

This immediately yields a dynamic programming algorithm. Indeed, given a generic vertex $v$ you can consider the set $X(v)$ of all vertices $x$ at distance at least $k$ from $v$ in $T_v$. You have:

$$
OPT[v] = \max \left\{0, \max_{x \in X(v)} \left\{ \sum_{i=0}^k r(x_i) + \sum_{u \in C_{T_v}(x)}  OPT[u] \right\} \right\}.
$$
Where a $\max$ over an empty set is $0$, and the outer $\max$ accounts for empty optimal solutions. (The outer max can be dropped if the rewards are always non-negative, which seems natural).

Since there are $n$ subproblems and the solution to each subproblem $OPT[v]$ can be found in time $O(n)$ (once the values $OPT[u]$ are known), the overall running time is $O(n^2)$.